# Why is this Bootstrap column acting up?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why is the content nesting itself inside of each list item? The content should all be on the same line. I've tried `floating` and changing the `position`, but nothing is working. How do I fix this?

```css
.icon-left{
    float:left;
    padding: 12px 25px 60px 15px;
    color:#4ECABE;
}
.text{
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 0 0 15px;
}
.text h4{
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="icon-left">
              <i class="fa fa-ticket fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h4>Get Free Books</h4>
               <p>Increase your chances to win by doing simple tasks - like watching videos :) </p>
            </div> <br>
            <div class="icon-left" id='smile'>
              <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="text2">
            <h4>New Books Every 6 Hours</h4>
               <p>That's right, you only have 6 hours to get entries for a book.</p>
            </div> <br>
            <div class="icon-left">
              <i class="fa fa-truck fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
            <h4>Absolutely free!</h4>
               <p>We even pay shipping.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. You can either apply `br { clear: both; }` with your existing markup, or a better way to do it with bootstrap is to wrap the `.icon-left` and `.text` elements in an element with the `.clearfix` class.

```css
.icon-left{
    float:left;
    padding: 12px 25px 60px 15px;
    color:#4ECABE;
}
.text{
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 0 0 15px;
}
.text h4{
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="icon-left">
      <i class="fa fa-ticket fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Get Free Books</h4>
      <p>Increase your chances to win by doing simple tasks - like watching videos :) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="icon-left" id='smile'>
      <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text2">
      <h4>New Books Every 6 Hours</h4>
      <p>That's right, you only have 6 hours to get entries for a book.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="icon-left">
      <i class="fa fa-truck fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Absolutely free!</h4>
      <p>We even pay shipping.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `.icon-left` divs a coloured background (e.g. `background: gold`) and it should become evident. The bottom padding extends past the non-float elements on the right, which is pushing the next row along.

Reducing the padding on `.icon-left` (for example to `padding: 12px 25px 24px 15px;`) should allow everything to snap back into line.

---

Slightly unrelated tip: add the class `fa-fw` to your FA icons to use fixed width icons, which will allow your text to line up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you have extra padding icon-left

try  padding: 12px 25px 25px 15px;

Also I would wrap every section with a div and a grid class col-lg-3 so you dont have to use this big padding, and will give you a better control on your UI.